# How to make rectangle with animated width React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, react-animated

I'm new to React Native. I need to create a custom slider and I think it can make with animations. So could you explain how to create this animation?

[image]

Comment: Does the animation preformed **during** a drag event or **after** a user press event?

Comment: @cowCrazy Animation performed during a drag event

Comment: In this case assuming you want it to be as native as possible take a look at [Reanimated](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-reanimated) if is not enough check also [GestureHandler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/handler-pan.html). Both from the same author and work well together. Sadly the `Animated` api of react native is not yet ready for what you wanna achieve.

Comment: @cowCrazy Is it possible to change style of Slider standard react-native component and make it like mine example?

Comment: Style you mean the Zibra lines or the X-offset of the slider?

Comment: @cowCrazy I mean to take slider component and set style like I need

Comment: Don't think it should be a problem, you just wrap your visual component with the slider component, which should give you the sliding functionality, but you can set its view and style.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a demo for that

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Animated } from 'react-native';
import GestureRecognizer, {swipeDirections} from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    widthAnim: new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  maxWidthAnimate = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.widthAnim , {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 2000
    });
  }

  minWidthAnimate = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.widthAnim , {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 2000
    });
  }

  render() {
    const width = this.state.widthAnim.interpolate(
      {
        inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
        outputRange: [50, 200, 50]
      }
    );
    return (
      <View>
        <GestureRecognizer
          onSwipeLeft={this.minWidthAnimate}
          onSwipeRight={this.maxWidthAnimate}
        >
            <Animated.View style={{width: width, height: 100, backgroundColor: "blue", borderBottomRightRadius: 100, borderTopRightRadius: 100}}>
            </Animated.View>
        </GestureRecognizer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an expo link: https://snack.expo.io/BJvTVMOSN

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I wanted but how to run an animation while controlling a finger (like a slider)?

Comment: This is almost what I need, but there is one question. Is it possible to set the value between the minimum and maximum? For example, take and pull until the value reaches the maximum or a certain value (value from 0 to 10, stops at 8)

Comment: You can see an example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YqrNTv7VKW4usBC9AQIz3frV_1Kjxn2N/view?usp=sharing)